# Retrieve data from mysql by php to create flot graph

Tags: php, flot

Hi i am trying to retrieve data from mysql database to create flot graph 
can anyone walk me through this procedure or give me an idea of what to do
thanks

Comment: At what point exactly do you need help? I assume you know basically how to extract the data from the database?

Comment: ya i know how to extract the data but how to create the flot

Comment: After fetching the array what should i do

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably want something like this. I haven't used flot but I looked at the example [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/basic.html).

```
<?php
//create array of pairs of x and y values
$dataset1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) { //or whatever
    $dataset1[] = array( $row['xvalue'], $row['yvalue'] );
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //put array into javascript variable
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;

    //plot
    $(function () {
         $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi i did as you said but it isn't working there is an exception 
$dataset1 = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
 {
  $dataset1[] = array( $row['msgCount'], $row['Group_ID'] );
 }
 echo json_encode($dataset1);

jquery 
 function plotGraph()
 {
  alert("In body");
  $.ajax({
   url:"getData.php",
   type:"post",
   datatype:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {alert(data);
   $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ data ]);
     },
   error:function()
   {alert("There was a problem");}
  })
 }
is there something missing

Comment: Hey Tom This example was really helpful but now i am facing a problem of handling the null because it is not plotted

Comment: @Sarah: I suppose you could convert them to zero - either in the query e,g IFNULL( colName, 0 ) or in your PHP loop by casting each value to an integer.

Comment: Thanks for this, was having trouble getting the json in from php to flot and this worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Adding upon the example from [@Tom Haigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22224/tom-haigh):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Flot Examples</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<?php

$server = "localhost";
    $user="user";
    $password="password";  
    $database = "some_database";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

query = "SELECT x_axis_values, y_axis_values FROM some_table";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['x_axis_value'],$row['y_axis_value']);
    }

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
});
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Came across this. Just trying to get it to work. I think you are missing a `$` from in front of `query`. Also the variable `$db` is only referenced once. Is that right? The above won't propagate anyway. Would love some help:)

Answer (score 2):

as @Tom Haigh say work well, but you need to add another code to work well, I was using the example, but I discover in the source code it add to the result quotes " so to avoid this just add the: intval to the array, example:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT valx, valy FROM chart";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $d2[] = array (intval($row['valx']),intval($row['valy']));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends largely on your environment and requirements. There's lots of free tools out there you can use. One example is [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) that lets you use jQuery to build graphs. There's link to documentation on the Google Code page.