# Parse PHP output as variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, flot

I'm trying to populate a Flot chart using the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312302/retrieve-data-from-mysql-by-php-to-create-flot-graph). I've been trying for hours, but can't get the PHP output to be parsed to the Javascript variable. To break it down here is the example with the hard coded data which works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
#placeholder { width: 450px; height: 200px; }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = [[1,7],[2,8],[3,7],[4,7]];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1]);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The series data used above is the output of a php file I have set up to query my mysql database. But when I combine the two into one .HTML page I am unable to parse the PHP output to the javascript plot area. Below is what I have...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
#placeholder { width: 450px; height: 200px; }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<?php

    $server = "myserver:1234";
    $user="dbuser";
    $password="userpass";  
    $database = "dbname";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT X, Y FROM dbtable";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['X'],$row['Y']);
    }
    $final = json_encode($dataset1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?>  

<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = <?php echo $final; ?>;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1]);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally I'd like to update this chart dynamically too if possible, but first things first! Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Change `var d1 = <?php $final; ?>;` to `var d1 = <?php echo $final; ?>;`

Comment: Sorry, typo creating the question. I have tried the echo, still a blank render. I'll update the question.

Comment: What does your browser console say? Does it output any errors? What's the output of `var_dump($final);`?

Comment: When I add var_dump to the standalone php script it's `string(2541) "[[1,7],[2,8],[3,7],[4,7]...]"` I think the php script, when embedded in the HTML doc isn't rendering properly somehow. But I can't see any errors. Where should I be looking?

Comment: That's good, but what about my first two questions?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Console says syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I combine the two into one **.HTML** page I am unable to parse the PHP output to the javascript plot area

PHP scripts need to have `.php` extension. If you try to output PHP code in an HTML page, it'll just get displayed as plain text. If you want the code to get executed (which you probably do), change the extension to `.php`.

Note that it's possible parse PHP in HTML pages with some [`.htaccess` tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7127156/1438393), but I doubt you need that.

Comment: Thanks for the chat! Honestly I would have gone in circles trying everything else and continued to completely overlook this.

Comment: @square_eyes: Glad to have been of help. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't echo $final variable

```
var d1 = <?php echo $final; ?>
```

Comment: What do you see if you see in the parsed html source?

Comment: Strange, the PHP tags for the DB query seem to be dropped.

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to be rendering to the page.

Comment: well, do you have php installed? does your file have a .php extension and are you accessing the file via http (in case you are on localhost)?

Comment: Yes PHP installed. My file is .HTML there is PHP embedded in it.

Comment: you need to change your file extension to .php

Comment: Yes I'm in a chat now. We just reached the same conclusion:) Still not rendering but getting there as the variable is now parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var d1 = <?=$final; ?>;
```

Comment: Can you var_dump($final); and console.log(d1); before your document ready

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually echo'ing out your result string.

```
<?= $final; ?>
```

Comment: What do `$final` and `d1` contain when your script executes?